# Decodable extension not called Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to decode the array IGNotification into data that was successfully encoded into a  dictionary. Below is my compactMap that should call my Decodable extension, however it looks like my extension is not being called or that the dictionary is not being serialized. Can someone help me as to why this is?

getNotifications function:

```
public func getNotifications(
    completion: @escaping ([IGNotification]) -> Void
) {
    guard let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username") else {
        completion([])
        return
    }
    let ref = firestoreDatabase.collection("users").document(username).collection("notifications")
    ref.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        guard let notifications = snapshot?.documents.compactMap({
            IGNotification(with: $0.data())
        }),
        error == nil else {
            completion([])
            return
        }

        completion(notifications)
        print(notifications)
    }
}
```

Decodable extension:

```
extension Decodable {
    /// Create model with dictionary
    /// - Parameter dictionary: Firestore data
    
    init?(with dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(
            withJSONObject: dictionary,
            options: .prettyPrinted)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(
            Self.self,
            from: data
        ) else {
            return nil
        }
        self = result
    }
}
```

Comment: If snapshot is `nil` then `compactMap` will never be called.  Is `snapshot` nil?

Comment: @ScottThompson snapshot is being called and is not nil. I just printed snapshot as "Optional(<FIRQuerySnapshot: 0x7f789cd69ed0>)".

Comment: Are you setting breakpoints? How many documents in `snapshot?.documents`?

Comment: @Rob I have not been setting breakpoints for debugging, I have been using print statements to debug but I will start using breakpoints as well. There are 19 documents in my Firestore database. When I use a print statement of 'print(snapshot?.documents)' 'Optional([])' is returned in the console. The documents are being inserted into the database properly, just decoding them from dictionary to be displayed in a table view is the issue

Comment: If `print(snapshot?.documents)` yields "Optional([])" then you don't have any documents to decode. That's your problem.

Comment: @Rob I see, why would that be the case if my notifications collection in Firestore database has plenty of documents in it?

Comment: I'm just speculating, but probably because you have something wrong here: `collection("users").document(username).collection("notifications")`. Look at the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference